# Dropping a range of partitions in HIVE

Tags: hive, hql

I have a Hive (ver 0.11.0) table partitioned by column date, of type string. I want to know if there exists a way in Hive by which I can drop partitions for a range of dates (say from 'date1' to 'date2'). I have tried the following (SQL type) queries, but they don't seem to be syntactically correct:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION
(date>='date1' and date<='date2');

ALTER TABLE myTable DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION
(date>='date1' && date<='date2');

ALTER TABLE myTable DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION
(date between 'date1' and 'date2');
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I tried this syntax it worked.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP PARTITION (dates>'2018-04-14',dates<'2018-04-16');
```

Command output:

```
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=107
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=110
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=112
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=14
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=157
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=159
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=177
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=208
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=22
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=233
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=234
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=76
    Dropped the partition dates=2018-04-15/country_id=83
    OK
    Time taken: 0.706 seconds
```

I am using, Hive 1.2.1000.2.5.5.0-157

Comment: I *think* this will drop everything on the table? Larger than 201-04-14 OR smaller than 2018-04-16...

Comment: @HeinduPlessis This is AND not OR.

Example: dates>'2018-04-14' and dates<'2018-04-16'

Comment: @HeinduPlessis, no, it will not drop other partitions, it ONLY drops those in between

Comment: @HeinduPlessis can you confirm that this answer is more elegant and up-to-date than my post on Aug.2017? (see above). If so, I will be happy to delete my misleading and outdated solution. Many thanks and best regards.

Comment: @vreyespue I think there's use for both - your script is much more dynamic, but for the OP's (and my) requirement, this answer is easier to apply.

Comment: @Kharthigeyan indeed I never realised it's an AND logic.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: `alter table myTable drop partition (unix_timestamp('date1','yyyy-MM-dd')>unix_timestamp(myDate,‌​'yyyy-MM-dd'),unix_t‌​imestamp('date2','yy‌​yy-MM-dd')<unix_time‌​stamp(myDate,'yyyy-M‌​M-dd'));`

Comment: What is here date1, date2 and myDate. Say you want to delete between 2018-11-01 and 2019-02-12?

Comment: Alter table mytable drop partition (myDate > '2018-11-01' , myDate < '2019-02-12')