# Why can i not use greater than '>=' in Partition Parentheses in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It was ok to use >= operator in Cloudera Hive sql, After migration to Databricks I am not able to use this operator in Partition Parentheses

```
ALTER TABLE tmprry.tmp_table DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (log_date >= $LOG_DATE_EXECUTE_TWO_DAYS_AGO AND log_date <= $LOGDATE ) PURGE;
```

On the notebook it gives me error:

> com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException:
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:  mismatched input
> '>=' expecting {')', ','}(line 2, pos 20)
>
> == SQL == ALTER TABLE tmprry.tmp_table DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION
> (log_date >= 20220130 ) PURGE
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This supposedly happens because the partition column is a string and we are using comparison operators.

You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531327/drop-partitions-from-spark?rq=1)

Comment: thank you for your answer, however partition column is INT : 
"""SHOW CREATE TABLE `tmprry`.`tmp_table ` 
(.... `country_id` INT,`log_date` INT, `hour` INT) 
USING delta 
PARTITIONED BY (log_date) """ 
Might i have missed something?