# Drop partitions in Hive with different date format in the same partition column

Tags: hive, comparison, date-format, hadoop-partitioning

I have 2 types of value in the partition column of string datatype:

1. `yyyyMMdd`
2. `yyyy-MM-dd`

E.g. there are partition column values `20200301`, `2020-03-05`, `2020-05-07`, `20200701`, etc.

I need to drop partitions less than `20200501` with a DDL statement like

```sql
alter table tblnm drop partition(partcol < 20200501);
```

When I drop partitions using `yyyy-MM-dd` format, only `2020-03-05` partition is dropped.
But when I drop partitions using `yyyyMMdd` format, `20200301` is dropped as well as all the partitions containing hyphen (`-`).

How to compare value by ignoring hyphen or by ignoring data that contains hyphen?
I can replace hyphen in the alter table query if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why all the partitions with hyphen get dropped is the comparison of strings in java: every `2020-XX-XX` string is less than every `2020XXXX` string.

To restrict partitions to those without hyphen you should [add a lower bound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50408713/9145106) to the DDL in the format `yyyy0101`:

```sql
alter table tblnm drop partition(partcol < 20200501, partcol >= 20200101);
```

Beware that the partitions for the previous years won't be dropped, but you're free to run something like

```sql
alter table tblnm drop partition(partcol <= 20191231, partcol >= 20190101);
```

whenever you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is helpful. But my scenario needs past n of years also.  Anyways thank u very much

Comment: 1 more doubt..  In impala i can able to drop partitions with regexp. After dropping is therr any way to reflect that in hive/hdfs

Comment: I'd probably look into [MSCK REPAIR TABLE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)) command